# Prolog program to find equality of two lists in any order

Tags: list, prolog, any, failure-slice

I wanted to write a Prolog program to find equality of two lists, where the order of elements
doesn't matter. So I wrote the following:

```
del(_, [], []) .
del(X, [X|T], T).  
del(X, [H|T], [H|T1]) :-
   X \= H,
   del(X, T, T1).

member(X, [X|_]).  
member(X, [_|T]) :- 
   member(X, T).

equal([], []).  
equal([X], [X]).  
equal([H1|T], L2) :-
   member(H1, L2),
   del(H1, L2, L3),
   equal(T, L3).
```

But when I give input like `equal([1,2,3],X).`, it doesn't show all possible values of `X`. Instead, the program hangs in the middle. What could be the reason?

Comment: i.e. Determining the equality of two sets

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
isSubset([],_).
isSubset([H|T],Y):-
    member(H,Y),
    select(H,Y,Z),
    isSubset(T,Z).
equal(X,Y):-
    isSubset(X,Y),
    isSubset(Y,X).
```

Comment: The member/2 before the select/3 is not needed. The equal/2 does not work correctly: It gives only one solution and then on redo it hangs: ?- equal([1,2,3],X).
X = [1, 2, 3] ;
Error: Execution aborted since memory low. Therefore voting down the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try using predicate that checks if one of sets is a permutation of other set:

```
delete(X, [X|T], T).

delete(X, [H|T], [H|S]):-
    delete(X, T, S).


permutation([], []).

permutation([H|T], R):-
    permutation(T, X), delete(H, R, X).
```

(Predicate taken from http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet3411.htm)

```
?- permutation([1,2,3],[3,1,2]).
true
```

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

The actual reason for the non-termination that you observed is this: the following clause does not constrain `L2` in any way, shape, or form.

```
equal([H1|T], L2) :- 
   member(H1, L2),
   del(H1, L2, L3),
   equal(T, L3).
```

So your query `?- equal([1,2,3], X).` implies proving the goal `member(_, L2)` which does not terminate universally. Therefore `equal([1,2,3], X)` cannot terminate universally, too!

For more information on how to explain non-termination of Prolog code read about [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)!

---

PS. Looking at the termination problem from a different angle, we see that the non-termination is, in fact, a *necessary consequence* in this case.

Why? Because you do not constrain the number of multiplicities, which makes the solution set infinite in size. The set cannot be represented by a finite number of answers (provided  you do not permit delaying goals).

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the multiplicities of the list elements,
check for sufficient instantiation with 
[`ground/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=ground/1), 
enforce it with
[`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/4609915), 
and eliminate duplicates with [`sort/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sort/2) like so:

```
same_elements(As, Bs) :-
   iwhen(ground(As+Bs), (sort(As,Es),sort(Bs,Es))).
```

Sample use with SWI Prolog 8.0.0:

```
?- same_elements([a,c,c,b,a,c], [c,b,b,a]).
true.

?- same_elements([a,b,b,a], [b,a,b,e]).
false.

?- same_elements([a,b,b,a], Xs).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
equal([],[]).
equal([Ha|Ta],[Hb|Tb]) :-
   Ha = Hb, lequal(Ta,Tb).
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
equal(X, Y) :-
    subtract(X, Y, []),
    subtract(Y, X, []).
```

Answer (score 1):

So why does `equal([1,2,3], X)` not terminate universally with your code?

Let's look at a [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice) of your code! What are failure slices? Here's the tag info:

> A failure-slice is a fragment of a Prolog program obtained by adding some goals `false`. Failure-slices help to localize reasons for universal non-termination of a pure monotonic Prolog program. They also help to give a lower bound for the number of inferences needed. It is a concrete [program-slicing](/questions/tagged/program-slicing) technique.

To create a failure slice:

- we insert `false` goals into the program
- while making sure that the fragment does not terminate with above goal.

```
del(_, [], [])  :- false.
del(X, [X|T], T) :- false.
del(X, [H|T], [H|T1]) :- false,
   dif(X, H),                    % note that the OP originally used `X \= H`
   del(X, T, T1).

member(X, [X|_]).  
member(X, [_|T]) :- 
   member(X, T).

equal([], []) :- false.
equal([X], [X]) :- false.
equal([H1|T], L2) :-
   member(H1, L2), false,
   del(H1, L2, L3),
   equal(T, L3).  

?- equal([1,2,3], _), false.     % note that `false` is redundant ...
** LOOPS **                      % ... as above `equal/2` cannot succeed.
```

So... what does above failure slice tell us? It says:

- To make the goal `equal([1,2,3], X)` terminate universally ...
- ... we **must change** at least one of the **remaining parts** (the ones not <s>striked-through</s>)!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using built-in predicate `msort/2`, then comparing the lists. It takes O(nlogn) time on SWI Prolog, whereas checking unsorted lists naively element-by-element would take O(n<sup>2</sup>) time.

```
lists_equal(List1, List2) :-
    msort(List1, Sorted1),
    msort(List2, Sorted2),
    Sorted1=Sorted2.
```

Here, sorting lists takes O(nlogn) time, and comparing them takes O(n) time on SWI Prolog, I don't know about other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly

```
equal([],[]).
equal([H|T],[H|T1]):-equal(T,T1).
```

Comment: This will not work if the lists contain the same items in different order.