# Finding Unique Items in a List

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a rule which decides whether an item `X` occurs exactly one in a list `L`.

```
unique(X, [X|T]):- !, \+ member(X, T).
unique(X, [_|T]):- unique(X, T).
```

The rule works for determining whether a value is unique within a list or nor, but when I try to get unique values within a list using `unique(X, [1,2,3,1,3,2,5,4,3,8]).` it returns just `false.` What I expected is this (like `member(X, list).`:

```
X = 5 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 8 ;
```

I'm a complete beginner and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Found this: http://computer-programming-forum.com/55-prolog/d2b17b566dad6b41.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using [`nth0/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=nth0/4) (or [`select/3`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select) as pointed out by @false):

```
unique(X, L) :-
    nth0(_, L, X, R),
    \+ member(X, R).
```

`nth0/4` 4th argument `R` is the list `L` with the element `X` removed. We simply check then that `X` is not in `R`.

#### Better version

```
unique(X, L) :-
    nth0(_, L, X, R),
    maplist(dif(X), R).
```

This fixes the problem pointed out by @false, though since you are a beginner I doubt this is of much interest to you.

This has the advantage of working in situations like this one:

```
?- unique(b, [X, Y, a]).
X = b,
dif(Y, b) ;
Y = b,
dif(X, b) ;
false.
```

Comment: @false Added an improved version.

Comment: Your second version is very nice because it just reuses existing recursive predicates, but is not itself recursive. However, there is a (procedural) price to pay for this elegance! `unique(a,[a,a|_])` does not terminate.

Comment: @false Yes, it has problems if `L` is not sufficiently ground. Your version is the better implementation, though this one is much more readable for a beginner while working for an acceptable subset of possible situations.

Comment: Minor comment: [`select(X, L, R)`](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#select) is more common (I did not know `nth0/4` at all).

Answer (score 8):

You have been using cut and an unsafe form of negation. Both have to be used with extreme care. An immediate fix would be to guard your program against uses it is not designed for:

```
unique(X, Xs) :-
   when_si(ground(X+Xs), your_unique(X, Xs)).
```

This uses `when_si/2` (formerly called `iwhen/2`) which is similar to `when/2` except that it does not delay:

```
:- meta_predicate(when_si(+, 0)).

when_si(Cond, G_0) :-
   when(Cond, ( Called = true, G_0 ) ),
   ( var(Called) -> throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) ; true ).
```

Above works for systems providing `when/2`. Below is for any ISO conforming system:

```
when_si(Cond, G_0) :-
   (  when_condition(Cond)
   -> ( Cond -> G_0 ; throw(error(instantiation_error,_)) )
   ;  throw(error(domain_error(when_condition, Cond),_))
   ).

when_condition(C) :-
   var(C),
   !,
   throw(error(instantiation_error,_)).
when_condition(ground(_)).
when_condition(nonvar(_)).
when_condition(?=(_, _)).
when_condition(( A, B )) :-
   when_condition(A),
   when_condition(B).
when_condition(( A ; B )) :-
   when_condition(A),
   when_condition(B).
```

On the other hand, it gets quite frustrating receiving instantiation errors all the time instead of real answers. So, let's make your program really pure!

Your second rule

```
unique(X, [_|Es]) :-
   unique(X, Es).
```

reads declaratively, right-to-left (that `:-` is an `←`)

> Provided `X` is a unique element of the list `Es`, then `X` is a unique element of the list `[_|Es]`.

in other words: Whenever I know that `X` is unique in `Es`, it will be also unique with **any** further element in `Es`. That conclusion is not true, consider to extend the list by `X`! You need some extra condition. Also, your first rule needs to be reformulated. This uses [`non_member/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/772868):

```
unique(X, [X|Es]) :-
   non_member(X, Es).
unique(X, [E|Es]) :-
   dif(X, E),
   unique(X, Es).
```

And here is another way using [`tfilter/3`](/a/22053194):

```
unique(X, Es) :-
   tfilter(=(X), Es, [_]).
```

The most efficient is probably the following which uses `if_/3` of `library(reif)`:

```
unique(X, [E|Es]) :-
   if_(X = E, non_member(E, Es), unique(X, Es) ).
```

Comment: Probably overkill for a beginner, but this is good reference for a "correct" implementation of this.

Comment: @Fatalize: The only overkill I see is that `iwhen/2` is not readily available.

Comment: The 2nd implementation of `iwhen/2` should probably test `acyclic_term(Cond)` and throw an `error(type_error(acyclic_term, Cond), _)` in case of failure.

Comment: @repeat: Not sure - why should acyclic terms be specific to `iwhen/2`?

Comment: `when/2` reports an error in case the condition is a cyclic term. So does the 1st implementation of `iwhen/2`... shouldn't the 2nd implementation behave the same?

Comment: @repeat: Which `when/2` are you referring to? `X = s(X), when(ground(X),false).` just fails

Comment: I'm talking about conditions like in `C = (C,C), when(C, false)`. or `C = (C ; bad)`. `when/2` rejects these, so should `iwhen/2` (2nd impl).

Comment: I was wrong, at least in part. It's not quite as easy as I saw it... *Some* cyclic terms should be rejected, others must be permitted.

Comment: @repeat: I only see this error in SWI, but not in SICStus 4.41

Comment: @repeat: only `C=(C,C),when(C,false)` in error in SWI, but not in SICStus 4.4.1- is 4.5 better? Difficult to give it a good error. Still, `type_error(callable,(C,C))` per analogiam 7.8.3.3 c seems more appropriate.

Comment: SICStus 4.5.0 is no different here than 4.4.1.  Actually, the error given by SWI (type error acyclic_term expected) confused me.

Comment: Rather something like `when_condition(Cond, _) :-
   var(Cond),
   !,
   throw(error(instantiation_error,_)).
when_condition(ground(_), _).
when_condition(nonvar(_), _).
when_condition(?=(_, _), _).
when_condition(Cond, Conds0) :-
   (  Cond = ( A, B )
   -> true
   ;  Cond = ( A ; B )
   ),
   (  member(Cond0, Conds0), Cond0 == Cond
   -> false /* TODO: raise proper error */
   ;  Conds = [Cond|Conds0],
      when_condition(A, Conds),
      when_condition(B, Conds)
   ).`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a homework question.

Try something like this.

```
unique(M, L) :- member(M, L), count(M, L, 1).  
count(M, [H|T], C) :- M = H, count(M, T, C1), C is C + 1.
...
```

When completed this gives...

```
?- unique(X, [1,2,3,1,3,2,5,4,3,8]).
X = 5 ;
X = 4 ;
X = 8 ;
false.
```

Edit:
Since answers have already been given... here's the slick one.

```
unique(Item, List) :-
  select(Item, List, L2),
  \+ member(Item, L2).
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy and pure method:

```
unique_elem_in_list(Elem, Lst) :-
    select(Elem, Lst, Rem),
    maplist(dif(Elem), Rem).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- unique_elem_in_list(E, [A,B,C]).
E = A,
dif(A, B),
dif(A, C) ;
E = B,
dif(B, A),
dif(B, C) ;
E = C,
dif(C, A),
dif(C, B).
```