# Prolog - Count the Number of Repetitions in a List

Tags: list, prolog

I'm writing a program in Prolog that counts the number of *uninterrupted* occurrences of the first value in a list.

So given, `repetitions(N, [a,a,a,a,a,b,c,a])`, the program would return `N = 5`.

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
repetitions(A,[]).
repetitions(A,[A|T]) :- repetitions(A,[_|T]), A is 1+A.
repetitions(A,[_|T]) :- repetitions(A,[A|T]).
```

Comment: Just be aware that an expression like `A is 1+A` will always fail because you cannot reassign a variable in Prolog once it is instantiated, except through backtracking. That's because, logically, the expression `A is 1+A` asks Prolog to find an `A` such that `A` has the same value as `1+A` when evaluated, which of course is not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a **relational** version:

```
repetitions(N, [First|Rest]) :-
        phrase(repetitions_(First, 1, N), Rest).

repetitions_(_, N, N) --> [].
repetitions_(First, N0, N) --> [First],
        { N1 #= N0 + 1 },
        repetitions_(First, N1, N).
repetitions_(First, N, N) --> [Other], { dif(First, Other) }, ... .

... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

The test case works as required:

```
?- repetitions(N, [a,a,a,a,a,b,c,a]).
N = 5 ;
false.
```

And moreover, we can also use this in **other directions**.

For example, what about a list with 3 element *in general*:

```
?- Ls = [A,B,C], repetitions(N, Ls).
Ls = [C, C, C],
A = B, B = C,
N = 3 ;
Ls = [B, B, C],
A = B,
N = 2,
dif(B, C) ;
Ls = [A, B, C],
N = 1,
dif(A, B) ;
false.
```

And what about all possible answers, fairly enumerated by *iterative deepening*:

```
?- length(Ls, _), repetitions(N, Ls).
Ls = [_8248],
N = 1 ;
Ls = [_8248, _8248],
N = 2 ;
Ls = [_8734, _8740],
N = 1,
dif(_8734, _8740) ;
Ls = [_8248, _8248, _8248],
N = 3 ;
Ls = [_8740, _8740, _8752],
N = 2,
dif(_8740, _8752) ;
etc.
```

It is a major attraction of logic programs that they can often be used in *several directions*.

See [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg), [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) and [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for more information about the mechanisms I used to achieve this generality.

We can also use this to answer the following question

> What does a list look like *such that* there are 3 repetitions of its first element?

Example:

```
?- repetitions(3, Ls).
Ls = [_2040, _2040, _2040] ;
Ls = [_2514, _2514, _2514, _2532],
dif(_2514, _2532) ;
Ls = [_2526, _2526, _2526, _2544, _2550],
dif(_2526, _2544) ;
Ls = [_2538, _2538, _2538, _2556, _2562, _2568],
dif(_2538, _2556) .
```

This requires only that a single further constraint be added to the solution above. I leave this as an easy exercise.

Comment: Such as `repetitions_mat(1, [a,a|_]).`.

Comment: With a suitable change that solves the last query as I show it, also `repetitions(1, [a,a|_])` will fail immediately! Also determinism can be improved with `if_/3`!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a DCG-based solution somewhat a variation to @mat's:

```
repetitions_II(N, [X|Cs]) :-
   phrase( ( reps(X, N), no(X) ), [X|Cs]).

no(X) -->
   ( [] | [Y], {dif(X,Y)}, ... ).

reps(_X, 0) -->
   [].
reps(X, N0) -->
   [X],
   { N0 #> 0, N1 #= N0-1 },
   reps(X, N1).
```

Two notable differences:

1mo) There is no use of a difference for maintaining the counter. Thus, constraints on the number can help to improve termination. A perfect clpfd-implementation would (or rather should) implement this with similar efficiency to a difference.

2do) The end `no//1` essentially encodes in a pure manner `\+[X]`.

The downside of this solution is that it still produces leftover choicepoints. To get rid of these, some more manual coding is necessary:

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).

repetitions_III(N, [X|Xs]) :-
   reps([X|Xs], X, N).

reps([], _, 0).
reps([X|Xs], C, N0) :-
   N0 #>= 0,
   if_(X = C, ( N1 #= N0-1, reps(Xs, C, N1) ), N0 = 0 ).
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach close to what you've done so far, using CLPFD:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

repetitions(N,[H|T]):-repetitions(N,[H|T],H).

repetitions(0,[],_).
repetitions(0,[H|_],H1):-dif(H,H1).
repetitions(N,[H|T],H):-repetitions(N1 ,T, H), N #= N1+1.
```

Examples:

```
?- repetitions(A,[a,a,a,a,a,b,c,a]).
A = 5 ;
false.

?- repetitions(2,[a,Y]).
Y = a.

?- repetitions(N,[a,a|_]).
N = 2 ;
N = 2 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 3 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 4 ;
N = 5 ;
N = 5 ;
N = 6 ;
N = 6 ....and goes on
```

Comment: Nice! Please see the test case posted by false: `?- repetitions(1, [a,a|_]).`. Ideally, this *terminates* with `false`!

Comment: @Mat, Thanks, I saw the above test case but I don't have come up with any solution...

Comment: Putting a constraint after the critical recursive goal means that it cannot improve termination.

Comment: Why not reorder the goals in the last clause? Wouldn't it be good?

Comment: @repeat why is that ? could you explain ??

Comment: As a good Prolog habit: "Whenever there are two goals in a conjunction, put the one with better behavior w.r.t. universal termination first." `(#=)/2` *always* terminates universally. `repetitions/3` OTOH may or may not terminate. The (universal) termination properties of the conjunction can *never* get worse by putting the `(#=)/2` goal first. It *may* get better. In your concrete case it would not bring an immediate improvement, but with an additional `N1 #>= 0` goal in front it would! Consider the query `?- repetitions(1,Xs).`. It would terminate universally then, but it does not now. HTH;)

Answer (score 1):

a compact definition, courtesy libraries [apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=foldl/4) and [yall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=yall)

```
?- [user].
repetitions(A,[H|T]) :- foldl([E,(C0,H0),(C1,H1)]>>(E==H0 -> succ(C0,C1), H1=H0 ; C0=C1, H1=_), T, (1,H), (A,_)).
|: true.

?- repetitions(A,[a,a,a,a,a,b,c,a]).
A = 5.
```

Comment: @false: I find `incorrectly`, in your comment, **strongly** subjective. Maybe you could reserve it for something bearing **undefined behaviour**.  Of course, I don't think its' the case for this answer, but in case, you should explain better, not to me, but to OP... and other readers as well

Comment: ... because `Y = a, repetitions(2,[a,Y]).` succeeds. So either `repetitions(2,[a,Y]).` produces an instantiation error or the solution `Y = a`. There is not much choice left.

Comment: Why don't you use something along [`iwhen/2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868) to shield off such situations? This would make your code much more accessible for beginners.