# Longest common prefix (LCP) of a list of strings

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif, prolog-cut, logical-purity

```
lcs([ H|L1],[ H|L2],[H|Lcs]) :-
    !,
    lcs(L1,L2,Lcs).
lcs([H1|L1],[H2|L2],Lcs):-
    lcs(    L1 ,[H2|L2],Lcs1),
    lcs([H1|L1],    L2 ,Lcs2),
    longest(Lcs1,Lcs2,Lcs),
    !.
lcs(_,_,[]).

longest(L1,L2,Longest) :-
    length(L1,Length1),
    length(L2,Length2),
    (  Length1 > Length2
    -> Longest = L1
    ;  Longest = L2
    ).
```

This is my code so far. How could I optimize it so that it prints the prefix, e.g.:

```
["interview", "interrupt", "integrate", "intermediate"]
```

should return `"inte"`

A bit rusty with Prolog, haven't done it in a while :)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code? Does it provide a solution? Or an incorrect solution? Having it "print" the prefix when it doesn't currently is a feature addition, not an "optimization".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, let's start with something related, but much simpler.

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).  % "abc" = [a,b,c]

prefix_of(Prefix, List) :-
   append(Prefix, _, List).

commonprefix(Prefix, Lists) :-
   maplist(prefix_of(Prefix), Lists).

?- commonprefix(Prefix, ["interview", "integrate", "intermediate"]).
   Prefix = []
;  Prefix = "i"
;  Prefix = "in"
;  Prefix = "int"
;  Prefix = "inte"
;  false.
```

(See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8269897/772868) answer, how printing character lists with double quotes is done.)

This is the part that is fairly easy in Prolog. The only drawback is that it doesn't give us the maximum, but rather all possible solutions including the maximum. Note that all strings do not need to be known, like:

```
?- commonprefix(Prefix, ["interview", "integrate", Xs]).
   Prefix = []
;  Prefix = "i", Xs = [i|_A]
;  Prefix = "in", Xs = [i, n|_A]
;  Prefix = "int", Xs = [i, n, t|_A]
;  Prefix = "inte", Xs = [i, n, t, e|_A]
;  false.
```

So we get as response a partial description of the last unknown word. Now imagine, later on we realize that `Xs = "induce"`. No problem for Prolog:

```
?- commonprefix(Prefix, ["interview", "integrate", Xs]), Xs = "induce".
   Prefix = [], Xs = "induce"
;  Prefix = "i", Xs = "induce"
;  Prefix = "in", Xs = "induce"
;  false.
```

In fact, it does not make a difference whether we state this in hindsight or just before the actual query:

```
?- Xs = "induce", commonprefix(Prefix, ["interview", "integrate", Xs]).
   Xs = "induce", Prefix = []
;  Xs = "induce", Prefix = "i"
;  Xs = "induce", Prefix = "in"
;  false.
```

Can we now based on this formulate the maximum? Note that this effectively necessitates some form of extra quantor for which we do not have any direct provisions in Prolog.  For this reason we have to limit us to certain cases we know will be safe. The easiest way out would be to insist that the list of words does not contain any variables. I will use [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/) for this purpose.

```
maxprefix(Prefix, Lists) :-
   iwhen(ground(Lists), maxprefix_g(Prefix, Lists)).

maxprefix_g(Prefix, Lists_g) :-
   setof(N-IPrefix, ( commonprefix(IPrefix, Lists_g), length(IPrefix, N ) ), Ns),
   append(_,[N-Prefix], Ns).   % the longest one
```

The downside of this approach is that we get instantiation errors should the list of words not be known.

Note that we made quite some assumptions (which I hope really hold). In particular we assumed that there is exactly one maximum. In this case this holds, but in general it could be that there are several independent values for `Prefix`. Also, we assumed that `IPrefix` will always be ground. We could check that too, just to be sure. Alternatively:

```
maxprefix_g(Prefix, Lists_g) :-
   setof(N, IPrefix^ ( commonprefix(IPrefix, Lists_g), length(IPrefix, N ) ), Ns),
   append(_,[N], Ns),
   length(Prefix, N),
   commonprefix(Prefix, Lists_g).
```

Here, the prefix does not have to be one single prefix (which it is in our situation).

The best, however, would be a purer version that does not need to resort to instantiation errors at all.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the purified variant of the code proposed (and subsequently retracted) by @CapelliC:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

:- use_module(library(reif)).

lists_lcp([], []).
lists_lcp([Es|Ess], Ls) :-
   if_((maplist_t(list_first_rest_t, [Es|Ess], [X|Xs], Ess0),
        maplist_t(=(X), Xs))
       , (Ls = [X|Ls0], lists_lcp(Ess0, Ls0))
       , Ls = []).

list_first_rest_t([], _, _, false).
list_first_rest_t([X|Xs], X, Xs, true).
```

Above [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) `maplist_t/3` is a variant of `maplist/2`
which works with term equality/inequality reification—`maplist_t/5` is just the same with higher arity:

```
maplist_t(P_2, Xs, T) :-
   i_maplist_t(Xs, P_2, T).

i_maplist_t([], _P_2, true).
i_maplist_t([X|Xs], P_2, T) :-
   if_(call(P_2, X), i_maplist_t(Xs, P_2, T), T = false).

maplist_t(P_4, Xs, Ys, Zs, T) :-
   i_maplist_t(Xs, Ys, Zs, P_4, T).

i_maplist_t([], [], [], _P_4, true).
i_maplist_t([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [Z|Zs], P_4, T) :-
   if_(call(P_4, X, Y, Z), i_maplist_t(Xs, Ys, Zs, P_4, T), T = false).
```

First here's a ground query:

```
?- lists_lcp(["a","ab"], []).
false.                                % fails (as expected)
```

Here are the queries presented in [@Fatalize's fine answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47469352/4609915).

```
?- lists_lcp(["interview",X,"intermediate"], "inte").
   X = [i,n,t,e]
;  X = [i,n,t,e,_A|_B], dif(_A,r)
;  false.

?- lists_lcp(["interview","integrate",X], Z).
   X = Z, Z = []
;  X = Z, Z = [i]
;  X = Z, Z = [i,n]
;  X = Z, Z = [i,n,t]
;  X = Z, Z = [i,n,t,e]
;  X = [i,n,t,e,_A|_B], Z = [i,n,t,e]
;  X = [i,n,t,_A|_B]  , Z = [i,n,t]  , dif(_A,e)
;  X = [i,n,_A|_B]    , Z = [i,n]    , dif(_A,t)
;  X = [i,_A|_B]      , Z = [i]      , dif(_A,n)
;  X = [_A|_B]        , Z = []       , dif(_A,i).

?- lists_lcp([X,Y], "abc").
   X = [a,b,c]      , Y = [a,b,c|_A]
;  X = [a,b,c,_A|_B], Y = [a,b,c]
;  X = [a,b,c,_A|_B], Y = [a,b,c,_C|_D], dif(_A,_C)
;  false.

?- lists_lcp(L, "abc").
   L = [[a,b,c]]
;  L = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c|_A]]
;  L = [[a,b,c,_A|_B],[a,b,c]]
;  L = [[a,b,c,_A|_B],[a,b,c,_C|_D]], dif(_A,_C)
;  L = [[a,b,c],[a,b,c|_A],[a,b,c|_B]]
;  L = [[a,b,c,_A|_B],[a,b,c],[a,b,c|_C]]
;  L = [[a,b,c,_A|_B],[a,b,c,_C|_D],[a,b,c]]
;  L = [[a,b,c,_A|_B],[a,b,c,_C|_D],[a,b,c,_E|_F]], dif(_A,_E) 
…
```

Last, here's the query showing improved determinism:

```
?- lists_lcp(["interview","integrate","intermediate"], Z).
Z = [i,n,t,e].                              % succeeds deterministically
```

Comment: Nice, but it seems we can take it a step further!

Comment: @false. Further?  More (&better) queries showing that answers do not "overlap"?

Comment: There is definitely a better way!

Comment: @false. A better implementation?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Different approach! Imagine you have `lcp/3`. That is, the lcp for two lists. And now ...

Comment: @false. What about universal termination in cases like `lists_lcp([X,Y], "abc")` ?

Comment: Your query possesses an infinite set of solution that cannot be described with a finite number of answers. So how can you maintain termination?

Comment: Rather: Approximate maximal efficiency for the cases that are comparable to traditional algorithms

Comment: @false. Really? What about `X = [a,b,c], Y = [a,b,c|_A] ;  X = [a,b,c,_A|_B], Y = [a,b,c] ;  X = [a,b,c,_A|_B], Y = [a,b,c,_C|_D], dif(_A,_C)` (see above)?

Comment: My reasoning was flawed. It;s just not only for `[X,Y]` but also larger lists!

Comment: (And... it seems the expansion of `(',')/3` is flawed, too. Some more meta-predicate issues are badly needed... 'elp!)

Answer (score 7):

Here is how I would implement this:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

longest_common_prefix([], []).
longest_common_prefix([H], H).
longest_common_prefix([H1,H2|T], P) :-
    maplist(append(P), L, [H1,H2|T]),
    (   one_empty_head(L)
    ;   maplist(head, L, Hs),
        not_all_equal(Hs)
    ).

one_empty_head([[]|_]).
one_empty_head([[_|_]|T]) :-
    one_empty_head(T).

head([H|_], H).

not_all_equal([E|Es]) :-
    some_dif(Es, E).

some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-
    if_(diffirst(X,E), true, some_dif(Xs,E)).

diffirst(X, Y, T) :-
    (   X == Y -> T = false
    ;   X \= Y -> T = true
    ;   T = true,  dif(X, Y)
    ;   T = false, X = Y
    ).
```

**The implementation of `not_all_equal/1` is from [this answer by @repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47491046/2554145)** (you can find my implementation in the edit history).

We use `append` and `maplist` to split the strings in the list into a prefix and a suffix, and where the prefix is the same for all strings. For this prefix to be the longest, we need to state that the first character of at least two of the suffixes are different.

This is why we use `head/2`, `one_empty_head/1` and `not_all_equal/1`. `head/2` is used to retrieve the first char of a string; `one_empty_head/1` is used to state that if one of the suffixes is empty, then automatically this is the longest prefix. `not_all_equal/1` is used to then check or state that at least two characters are different.

#### Examples

```
?- longest_common_prefix(["interview", "integrate", "intermediate"], Z).
Z = [i, n, t, e] ;
false.

?- longest_common_prefix(["interview", X, "intermediate"], "inte").
X = [i, n, t, e] ;
X = [i, n, t, e, _156|_158],
dif(_156, r) ;
false.

?- longest_common_prefix(["interview", "integrate", X], Z).
X = Z, Z = [] ;
X = [_246|_248],
Z = [],
dif(_246, i) ;
X = Z, Z = [i] ;
X = [i, _260|_262],
Z = [i],
dif(_260, n) ;
X = Z, Z = [i, n] ;
X = [i, n, _272|_274],
Z = [i, n],
dif(_272, t) ;
X = Z, Z = [i, n, t] ;
X = [i, n, t, _284|_286],
Z = [i, n, t],
dif(_284, e) ;
X = Z, Z = [i, n, t, e] ;
X = [i, n, t, e, _216|_224],
Z = [i, n, t, e] ;
false.

?- longest_common_prefix([X,Y], "abc").
X = [a, b, c],
Y = [a, b, c|_60] ;
X = [a, b, c, _84|_86],
Y = [a, b, c] ;
X = [a, b, c, _218|_220],
Y = [a, b, c, _242|_244],
dif(_218, _242) ;
false.

?- longest_common_prefix(L, "abc").
L = [[a, b, c]] ;
L = [[a, b, c], [a, b, c|_88]] ;
L = [[a, b, c, _112|_114], [a, b, c]] ;
L = [[a, b, c, _248|_250], [a, b, c, _278|_280]],
dif(_248, _278) ;
L = [[a, b, c], [a, b, c|_76], [a, b, c|_100]] ;
L = [[a, b, c, _130|_132], [a, b, c], [a, b, c|_100]];
…
```

Comment: `longest_common_prefix([[A],[B],[b]], []), A=a,B=b.` gives two identical solutions?

Comment: @false My implementation introduces redundant `dif` constraints that I don't see how to avoid.

Comment: Up to `not_all_equal_/1` this is a highly Prologish approach!

Comment: @false I am in the process of writing a question on the implementation of `not_all_equal`, because it seems like a useful predicate bu a difficult one to implement properly…

Comment: but how would I then join the list of characters together, eg [i,n,t,e] as "inte"?
 @false

Comment: Please note that with the Prolog flag set as above, `[i,n,t,e] = "inte"`! So they are the same. Seem my answer how to get "inte" written as shown above!

Answer (score 7):

[This previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47553463/4609915) presented an implementation based on `if_/3`.

```
:- use_module(library(reif)).
```

Here comes a somewhat different take on it:

```
lists_lcp([], []).
lists_lcp([Es|Ess], Xs) :-
   foldl(list_list_lcp, Ess, Es, Xs).                % foldl/4

list_list_lcp([], _, []).
list_list_lcp([X|Xs], Ys0, Zs0) :-
   if_(list_first_rest_t(Ys0, Y, Ys)                 % if_/3
      , ( Zs0 = [X|Zs], list_list_lcp(Xs, Ys, Zs) )
      ,   Zs0 = []
      ).

list_first_rest_t([], _, _, false).
list_first_rest_t([X|Xs], Y, Xs, T) :-
   =(X, Y, T).                                       % =/3
```

*Almost* all queries in my previous answer give the same answers, so I do not show them here.

`lists_lcp([X,Y], "abc")`, however, does not terminate universally anymore with the new code.

Comment: This `list_first_rest_t`, can't this be expressed more succinctly?

Comment: ... like a conjunction of simpler conditions?

Comment: Yes, Ys0 = [X|Ys]. OTOH this would make some residual `dif/2` goals more complex... worth it?

Comment: for some reason when i run the code it crashes, it says "stack.pl:6: Singleton variables: [Y]" @repeat

Comment: @blazing. Which query are you running? This `stack.pl`-message does not make much sense to me. Please provide more data showing the problems you encountered.

Comment: the code doesn't compile, I tried to run it on swipl in my terminal but it didn't just gave me that error @repeat

Comment: @blazing. Download and install `library(reif)`. I added a link in my answer.

Comment: @blazing. Be specific about the error you get! "That error" doesn't help me localize where the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

A simple version:

```
:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).
pref([],_,[]).
pref(_,[],[]).
pref([H|T1],[H|T2],[H|Tr]):-
    pref(T1,T2,Tr).
pref([H|_],[H|_],[]).
pref([H1|_],[H2|_],[]):-
    dif(H1,H2).

lcf([],[]).
lcf([W],R):-
    pref(W,W,R).
lcf([W1,W2|L],R):-
    pref(W1,W2,R),
    lcf([W2|L],R).
```

Examples:

```
pref("interview","integrate",R).
R = [i, n, t, e] ;
R = [i, n, t] ;
R = [i, n] ;
R = [i] ;
R = [] ;
False.

lcf(["interview", "interrupt", "integrate", "intermediate"],R).
R = [i, n, t, e]

lcf(["interview", "interrupt", X, "intermediate"],R).
R = X, X = [i, n, t, e, r]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to implement this for two lists, and this is the code I came up with. It assumes the two input lists are sufficiently instantiated.

```
longest_common_prefix([X|Xs], [X|Ys], [X|Common]) :- !,
    longest_common_prefix(Xs, Ys, Common).
longest_common_prefix(_, _, []).
```

This is easily extended to multiple lists:

```
lcs([], []).
lcs([L1|Ls], Prefix) :-
    foldl(longest_common_prefix, Ls, L1, Prefix).
```

If you don't like using `foldl`:

```
lcs([], []).
lcs([L1|Ls], Prefix) :-
    lcs(Ls, L1, Prefix).

lcs([], Prefix, Prefix).
lcs([L1|Ls], Prefix0, Prefix) :-
    longest_common_prefix(L1, Prefix0, Prefix1),
    lcs(Ls, Prefix1, Prefix).
```