# How to implement a not_all_equal/1 predicate

Tags: list, prolog, predicate, prolog-dif, logical-purity

How would one implement a `not_all_equal/1` predicate, which succeeds if the given list contains at least 2 different elements and fails otherwise?

Here is my attempt (a not very pure one):

```
not_all_equal(L) :-
    (   member(H1, L), member(H2, L), H1 \= H2 -> true
    ;   list_to_set(L, S),
        not_all_equal_(S)
    ).

not_all_equal_([H|T]) :-
    (   member(H1, T), dif(H, H1)
    ;   not_all_equal_(T)
    ).
```

This however does not always have the best behaviour:

```
?- not_all_equal([A,B,C]), A = a, B = b.
A = a,
B = b ;
A = a,
B = b,
dif(a, C) ;
A = a,
B = b,
dif(b, C) ;
false.
```

In this example, only the first answer should come out, the two other ones are superfluous.

Comment: I'd probably call it `not_all_same` since "equal" has a bit of a numeric connotation to it. :)

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30863784/772868).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a straightforward way you can do it and **preserve [logical-purity](/questions/tagged/logical-purity)!**

```
not_all_equal([E|Es]) :-
   some_dif(Es, E).

some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-
   (  dif(X, E)
   ;  X = E, some_dif(Xs, E)
   ).
```

Here are some sample queries using SWI-Prolog 7.7.2.

First, the most general query:

```
?- not_all_equal(Es).
   dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_A,_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_A,_A,_A,_B|_C]
...
```

Next, the query the OP gave in the question:

```
?- not_all_equal([A,B,C]), A=a, B=b.
   A = a, B = b
;  false.                          % <- the toplevel hints at non-determinism
```

Last, let's put the subgoal `A=a, B=b` upfront:

```
?- A=a, B=b, not_all_equal([A,B,C]).
   A = a, B = b
;  false.                          % <- (non-deterministic, like above)
```

Good, but ideally the last query should have succeeded deterministically!

---

#### Enter `library(reif)`

[First argument indexing](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/Indexing.html) 
takes the principal functor of the first predicate argument (plus a few simple built-in tests) into account to improve the determinism of sufficiently instantiated goals.

This, by itself, does *not* cover `dif/2` satisfactorily.

What can we do? Work with
[reified term equality/inequality](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13664870/4609915)—effectively [indexing `dif/2`](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01590)!

```
some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-                     % some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-
   if_(dif(X,E), true,                     %    (  dif(X,E), true
       (X = E, some_dif(Xs,E))             %    ;  X = E, some_dif(Xs,E)
      ).                                   %    ).
```

Notice the similarities of the new and the old implementation!

Above, the goal `X = E` is redundant on the left-hand side. Let's remove it!

```
some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-
   if_(dif(X,E), true, some_dif(Xs,E)).
```

*Sweet!* But, alas, we're not quite done (yet)!

```
?- not_all_equal(Xs).
DOES NOT TERMINATE
```

*What's going on?*

It turns out that the implementation of `dif/3` prevents us from getting a nice answer sequence for the most general query. To do so—without using additional goals forcing fair enumeration—we need a tweaked implementation of `dif/3`, which I call `diffirst/3`:

```
diffirst(X, Y, T) :-
   (  X == Y -> T = false
   ;  X \= Y -> T = true
   ;  T = true,  dif(X, Y)
   ;  T = false, X = Y
   ).
```

Let's use `diffirst/3` instead of `dif/3` in the definition of predicate `some_dif/2`:

```
some_dif([X|Xs], E) :-
   if_(diffirst(X,E), true, some_dif(Xs,E)).
```

So, at long last, here are above queries with the new `some_dif/2`:

```
?- not_all_equal(Es).                     % query #1
   dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_B|_C]
;  dif(_A,_B), Es = [_A,_A,_A,_B|_C]
...

?- not_all_equal([A,B,C]), A=a, B=b.      % query #2
   A = a, B = b
;  false.

?- A=a, B=b, not_all_equal([A,B,C]).      % query #3
A = a, B = b.
```

Query #1 does not terminate, but has the same nice compact answer sequence. **Good!**

Query #2 is still non-determinstic. Okay. To me this is as good as it gets.

Query #3 has become deterministic: **Better now!**

---

**The bottom line:**

1. Use `library(reif)` to tame excess non-determinism while preserving logical purity!
2. `diffirst/3` should find its way into `library(reif)` :)

---

---

---

**EDIT:** more general using a [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate) (suggested by a comment; thx!)

Let's generalize `some_dif/2` like so:

```
:- meta_predicate some(2,?).
some(P_2, [X|Xs]) :-
   if_(call(P_2,X), true, some(P_2,Xs)).
```

`some/2` can be used with reified predicates other than `diffirst/3`.

Here an update to `not_all_equal/1` which now uses `some/2` instead of `some_dif/2`:

```
not_all_equal([X|Xs]) :-
   some(diffirst(X), Xs).
```

Above sample queries still give the same answers, so I won't show these here.

Comment: For some reason applying the diff on the first element of the list is confusing but it really covers all cases after thinking about it more... should not have overthought it!

Comment: That took me by surprise, too! Looking back at it now it is quite obvious and a direct translation of the original problem statement.

Comment: Nice and appropriate over-generalization! However, is **that** the reason why you think `dif/3` should enumerate answers differently? I suspect that there is another predicate where the other order is better. Pure coincidence that enumeration happens to work with your approach.

Comment: What about reformulating `some_dif(Es, E).` as, say `some(Es, dif(E))`?

Comment: ... or rather `some(dif(E), Es)`

Comment: @false. I like `some/2` with an argument order like `maplist/2`! Will edit.

Comment: @false. No, `dif/3` only got me thinking if `if_/3` wouldn't be even more alluring...

Comment: @false. I also see that this property could be hard to implement when, say, using `not/3`.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial implementation using `library(reif)` for [SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl)|[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl). It's certainly correct, as it produces an error when it is unable to proceed. But it lacks the generality we'd like to have.

```
not_all_equalp([A,B]) :-
   dif(A,B).
not_all_equalp([A,B,C]) :-
   if_(( dif(A,B) ; dif(A,C) ; dif(B,C) ), true, false ).
not_all_equalp([A,B,C,D]) :-
   if_(( dif(A,B) ; dif(A,C) ; dif(A,D) ; dif(B,C) ; dif(B,D) ), true, false ).
not_all_equalp([_,_,_,_,_|_]) :-
   throw(error(representation_error(reified_disjunction),'C\'est trop !')).

?- not_all_equalp(L).
   L = [_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_B,_C], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A,_A,_B], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_A,_B,_C], dif(_A,_B)
;  L = [_A,_B,_C,_D], dif(_A,_B)
;  error(representation_error(reified_disjunction),'C\'est trop !').
?- not_all_equalp([A,B,C]), A = a, B = b.
   A = a, B = b
;  false.
```

Edit: Now I realize that I do not need to add that many `dif/2` goals at all! It suffices that *one* variable is different to the first one! No need for mutual exclusivity! I still feel a bit insecure to remove the `dif(B,C)` goals ...

```
not_all_equalp([A,B]) :-
   dif(A,B).
not_all_equalp([A,B,C]) :-
   if_(( dif(A,B) ; dif(A,C) ), true, false ).
not_all_equalp([A,B,C,D]) :-
   if_(( dif(A,B) ; dif(A,C) ; dif(A,D) ), true, false ).
not_all_equalp([_,_,_,_,_|_]) :-
   throw(error(representation_error(reified_disjunction),'C\'est trop !')).
```

The answers are exactly the same... what is happening here, me thinks. Is this version weaker, that is less consistent?

Comment: IMO `?- dif(X,Y,T).` would *really* benefit from having the same solution order as `( T = true, dif(X,Y) ; T = false, X=Y )` !

Comment: Actually, this goes beyond `dif/3`; it's a coding convention for reified predicates which I'd like to propose. Why? (1) It gives a bit more control to `library(reif)` users, in a intuitive way. (2) It stresses the similarity to conventional Prolog disjunction. (3) The answer sequence would start out the same. Additional answers (missing when using `(->)/2` or `if/3`) would *not* be presented up-front. According to "communication 101": to reach an agreement, first stress the common and *then* expand on it (not vice versa)... does that make sense to you? Will write up an answer to this question.