# Inserting a cut in Prolog to make a relation clause bound but bidirectional

Tags: prolog, prolog-cut

Consider the following Prolog program:

```
transform([], []).
transform([X | Xs],[Y | Ys]):-
    isSpecial(X),
    isSpecial(Y),
    transformSpecial(X,Y),
    transform(Xs,Ys).
transform([X | Xs],[ X | Ys]):-
    transform(Xs,Ys).

isSpecial(foo).
isSpecial(bar).
isSpecial(foobar).

transformSpecial(X,Y):-
    isSpecial(X),
    isSpecial(Y),
    not(X = Y).
```

There are cases where I will call `tranform([foo, 1, 2], X)` and cases where I want to call `transform(X, [foo, 1, 2])`.

In both cases I want X to unify with `[bar, 1, 2]` and with `[foobar, 1, 2]`, but not with `[foo, 1, 2]`. That is, I want that once the predicate correctly recognizes that the second clause is applicable it should stick to only backtrack using the second clause.

Where should I insert the cut to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is currently too general. After all, there are three solutions to your query, but only the first are intended.  The last one is wrong.

```
?- transform([foo, 1, 2], Xs).
   Xs = [bar, 1, 2]
;  Xs = [foobar, 1, 2]
;  Xs = [foo, 1, 2], unexpected.   % wrong
```

The cut now may reduce the number of solutions.  But most of the time this goes very wrong. Your question where you should "insert the cut to achieve this behavior?" has only as answer: there is no place.  You need to do much more to achieve this.

Essentially, what you are describing is an element-wise transformation. So maybe we stick with describing one element at a time.

```
el_transformed(X, Y) :-
    isSpecial(X),
    isSpecial(Y),
    dif(X,Y).
el_transformed(X, X).   % too general!
```

Use `maplist(el_transformed, [foo, 1, 2], Xs)` as before...

Note that this version is just as wrong as your original code. But now, it is simple to add the extra condition:

```
el_transformed(X, Y) :-
   isSpecial(X),
   isSpecial(Y),
   dif(X,Y).
el_transformed(X, X) :-
   dif(X, foo),
   dif(X, bar),
   dif(X, foobar).
```

There is one big drawback: This version is not very deterministic for certain cases:

```
?- el_transformed(foobar, bar).
   true
;  false.
```

If you want to get even more out of it, consider to use `library(reif)` available both
for
[SICStus](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/sicstus/reif.pl) and
[SWI](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/swi/reif.pl).

```
el_transformed(X, Y) :-
   if_(( ( X = foo ; X = bar ; X = foobar ),
         ( Y = foo ; Y = bar ; Y = foobar ) ),
       dif(X,Y),
       X = Y).
```

With this formulation we do not need to repeat ourselves. To check, if the code is fine, let's try the most general query:

```
?- el_transformed(X, Y).
   X = foo, Y = bar
;  X = foo, Y = foobar
;  X = bar, Y = foo
;  X = bar, Y = foobar
;  X = foobar, Y = foo
;  X = foobar, Y = bar
;  X = Y, dif(Y,foobar), dif(Y,bar), dif(Y,foo).
```

You are looking at all possible cases that can happen!  There are no further cases to consider.

So as a rule of thumb: Whenever you want a predicate that should work "bidirectionally", consider to write it as "omnidirectional" instead!

---

Maybe you did not like the explicit mentioning of `X = foo ; X = bar ; X = foobar`, in that case, we would have to dig deeper, by reifying `isSpecial/1` to `isSpecial_t/2`:

```
isSpecial_t(X, T) :-
   call(
      ( X = foo
      ; X = bar
      ; X = foobar
      ), T).

el_transformed(X, Y) :-
   if_( ( isSpecial_t(X), isSpecial_t(Y) ), dif(X, Y) , X = Y ).
```

Comment: The tip about converting this in a maplist is a good one, I will use it. However, your answer sidesteps my main problem: I need an automatic way of saying "none of the previous clauses are applicable" where you wrote the dif statements, since in my real use case I have like 10 clauses and writing all those safeguards would make the code illegible

Comment: @Jsevillamol: Using `dif/2` was the first step, but the solutions thereafter do not repeat the actual conditions.

Comment: If you want the explicit opposite of a predicate, you would need constructive negation - that is far off...

Answer (score 4):

Here is another approach that reuses your existing definition of `isSpecial/1`. It's biggest drawback is that it makes a lot of assumptions that are not readily visible. So even a small extension might invalidate it. It uses [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868) ("instantiated when").

```
el_transformed(X, Y) :-
   iwhen(( nonvar(X) ; nonvar(Y) ), iel_transformed(X, Y) ).

iel_transformed(X, Y) :-
   (  nonvar(X)
   -> ( isSpecial(X) -> isSpecial(Y), X \= Y ; X = Y )
   ;  ( isSpecial(Y) -> isSpecial(X), X \= Y ; X = Y )
   ).
```

Very tricky - I even made <s>a</s> two mistakes on my first try ... and no cut, mince!

For the most general query, we now get an instantiation error. Not very satisfying, but better than an incorrect result.

In general, you would have to look for implementations of [constructive negation](https://scholar.google.at/scholar?q=constructive+negation) to handle this in the general case...