# SWI-Prolog: How to stop the predicate when the list is empty? (predicate included)

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, predicate, backtracking

```
course(cmput325).
course(cmput175).
course(cmput201).
course(cmput204).
prerequisite(cmput204, cmput325).
prerequisite(cmput175, cmput201).
prerequisite(cmput175, cmput204).
```

I need to write a new predicate, which is

```
can_take(+L,?C).
```

Definition:

L is a given list of courses that a student has already taken. If C is also given,then the predicate should check whether the student has all the required courses for C. If C is a variable, then with backtracking, the predicate should produce one course at a time that the student can take now. Courses can be in any order, but each course should be generated only once, and you should not return any courses that the student has already taken.

Example:

```
?- findall(C, can_take([cmput175], C), L).
should return

L = [cmput201, cmput204].
```

Here is my predicate:

```
can_take(L,C) :- prerequisite(L,C).
can_take([L|List],C) :- prerequisite(L,C),can_take(List,C).
```

This predicate didn't return the correct result, and it just returned false. I think it is because I didn't determine the condition when L is empty, however, if I tried to add L \== [] in either of them. It still gave me error...what should I do so that this predicate will stop and give me result?

-------update-------

```
pre(X,C) :- prerequisite(X,C).   
pre(X,C) :- prerequisite(X,Y), pre(Y,C).

pre2(C,L) :- findall(L1,pre(L1,C),L).

required(C,L) :- pre2(C,L1),sort(L1,L).

can_take([],_).
can_take(L,C) :- required(C,L).
can_take([L|List],C) :- prerequisite(L,C),can_take(List,C).
```

Here is my code test:

```
?- required(cmput325,L).
L = [cmput175, cmput204].

?- required(cmput204,L).
L = [cmput175].

?- can_take([cmput175],X).
X = cmput201 ;
X = cmput204 ;

?- findall(C, can_take([cmput175], C), L).
L = [cmput201, cmput204].


?- can_take([cmput204],cmput325).
false. (this one is OK)

?- can_take([cmput175,cmput204],cmput325).
true ;
false. (this one is OK)

?- can_take([cmput175],cmput204).
true ;
true ;
false.
```

the last one is not ok because I don't want it to return two true statements...so what I want is just let it stop when either second or last line returns true. For my assignment, I am not allowed to use cut operator !, is there any other way to do it?

Comment: When you add `L \== []`, you will make things worse as you add a further condition.

Comment: @false: that would yield wrong results for the query `findall(C, can_take([], C), L).`

Comment: @gusbro: so is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: @gusbro: oh, wait, can_take([]._)actually worked, i added this fact instead of replacing my first fact.(I checked findall, it actually worked as well)

Comment: @CodeVanessa: what are you getting with this query `findall(C, can_take([], C), L).` which would be asking which courses you can take when you have not taken any prior courses ?

Comment: @gusbro: You are right.

Comment: There is a lot implicit here: Is it possible to have several prerequisites for a single course?

Comment: @false: yes, it is possible, I updated the question.

Comment: @gusbro: updated the question, there is another problem now...and if I have not taken any prior courses, the result will just be false.

Answer (score 3):

(I will assume that you can take a course a second time, even if you have taken it already. That at least are the rules I know of.)

> You can take a course, provided you have taken all required courses already.

There is no direct "all" in Prolog.  But you can formulate this differently

> You can take a course, provided there is no required course that you have not taken already.

```
can_take(Takens, Next) :-
    course(Next),
    iwhen( ground(Takens), 
           \+ ( prerequisite(Required, Next), \+ member(Required, Takens) ) ).
```

This uses [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868) to guard against cases where `Takens` is not fully instantiated.

Note that there is a slight difference to your examples:

```
?- findall(C, can_take([cmput175], C), L).
   L = [cmput175, cmput201, cmput204].
%       ^^^^^^^^
```

---

<sub><sup>**Disclaimer**

Your problem is inherently non-monotonic: By adding further facts for requirements you are reducing the number of possible courses you may take. As a beginner, rather stick to problems that are monotonic in nature.  It is on this side where Prolog really excels.</sup></sub>

Comment: uh, actually the correct result for ?- findall(C, can_take([cmput175], C), L). is L = [cmput201, cmput204].

Comment: @CodeVanessa:  That's not what you stated.

Comment: @CodeVanessa it is easy to fix. First, by stating that `L` is required to be fully ground, you don't need to guard against it being not fully ground, then you just add a member call to it, to get: `can_take(Takens, Next) :-
    course(Next),
    \+ ( prerequisite(Required, Next), \+ member(Required, Takens) ),
    \+ member( Next, Takens).`. by *starting* with `course(Next)`, it guarantees there won't be any duplicates, too. *generate* a possible candidate, then test its suitability.

Comment: in e.g. C they don't care if a caller misuses some function; they call it "undefined behavior" and move on.

Comment: @Will: Code exposing undefined behavior in C is not recommended here on SO.

Comment: @false thanks for the reference! (I believed you the first time, too :) ). two more follow-ups: a. why not simply `ground(Takens) -> course(Next), \+ (...) ; error(....)`, and b. both (a.) and your `when` use cut internally, while OP stated *no cuts*. So maybe while they are learning, and not writing production code, the less clean code is unavoidable. ... or maybe your `if_/3` can help...

Comment: ad a) `iwhen/2` is the strict brother of `when/2` which does coroutining. So everything is thus expressed in the same way. Also, in your case it is possible to add further conditions that are not only testing, think of `ground(Takens), Next = cs123` which is no longer valid. And, the error handling is something you would have to handle explicitly. b the cut in `iwhen/2` after `var/1` is a green cut to permit fast indexing. Enfin, a really green cut!