# How to negate in prolog?

Tags: prolog, negation

I can't understand how the negation works in Prolog. I followed some questions on the same topic but I still can't figure it out, so, sorry if this is repetitive
Say I have this rules:

```
female(mary).
female(sandra).
female(juliet).
female(lisa).
male(peter).
male(paul).
male(dony).
male(bob).
male(harry).
parent(bob, lisa).
parent(bob, paul).
parent(bob, mary).
parent(juliet, lisa).
parent(juliet, paul).
parent(juliet, mary).
parent(peter, harry).
parent(lisa, harry).
parent(mary, dony).
parent(mary, sandra).
```

What I'm trying to achieve is getting the combinations of all non-parent relationship:
I tried like this:

```
not_parent(X, Y) :- \+parent(X, Y).
```

this works for `not_parent(bob, juliet)` but for `not_parent(X, Y)` just shows `false`.
I saw this example and tried this too:

```
father_of(X, Y):-male(X), parent(X, Y). 
mother_of(X, Y):-female(X), parent(X, Y).


not_parent(X, Y):- 
    male(X), \+ father_of(X, Y);
    female(X), \+ mother_of(X, Y).
```

but this doesn't quite work, as it only shows names for X and not X, Y as I intended to.

Answer (score 1):

[Negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure) is known as *weak negation*, and works as expected only under the [closed world assumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-world_assumption).
This means in practical terms that you must supply 'enough instantiated' goals to the `(\+)/1` operator.
I would try - for simplicity - to introduce a genderless predicate, like `person/1`, and then I would ask for:

```
person(P) :- female(P) ; male(P).
not_parent(X,Y) :- person(X),person(Y),X@<Y,\+parent(X,Y).
```

Comment: The closed world assumption has nothing to do with insufficient instantiation of terms which is a Prolog specific problem that can be safely circumvented by insisting on fully instantiated (ground) goals (with `when/2` or just [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868)). These are safe and not complete remedies, indeed. And, why not use `dif/2` in your example...

Comment: @false: `why not use dif/2...` because of Occam' razor, or more simply because the Prologs I'm mostly interested into don't implement that construct.