# Set union in prolog with variables

Tags: variables, prolog, set, union

I am searching some SWI-Prolog function which is able to make some set union with variables as parameters inside. My aim is to make the union first and define the parameters at further on in source code.

Means eg. I have some function `union` and the call `union(A, B, A_UNION_B)` makes sense. Means further more the call:

```
union(A, [1,2], C), A=[3].
```

would give me as result

```
C = [3, 1, 2].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub><sup>(What you call `union/3` is most probably just concatenation, so I will use `append/3` for keeping this answer short.)</sup></sub>

What you expect is impossible without delayed goals or constraints. To see this, consider the following [failure-slice](/questions/tagged/failure-slice)

```
?- append(A, [1,2], C), false, A=[3].
   loops, unexpected.  % observed, but for us unexpected
   false.  % expected, but not the case
```

This query must terminate, in order to make the entire question useful. But there are infinitely many lists of different length for `A`. So in order to describe all possible solutions, we would need infinitely many answer substitutions, like

```
?- append(A, [1,2], C).
   A = [], C = [1,2]
;  A = [_A], C = [_A,1,2]
;  A = [_A,_B], C = [_A,_B,1,2]
;  A = [_A,_B,_C], C = [_A,_B,_C,1,2]
;  ... .
```

The only way around is to describe that set of solutions with finitely many answers.  One possibility could be:

```
?- when((ground(A);ground(C)), append(A,B,C)).
   when((ground(A);ground(C)),append(A,B,C)).
```

Essentially it reads: Yes, the query is true, provided the query is true.

While this solves your exact problem, it will now delay many otherwise succeeding goals, think of `A = [X], B = []`.

A more elaborate version could provide more complex tests. But it would require a somehow different definition than `append/3` is. Some systems like [sicstus-prolog](/questions/tagged/sicstus-prolog) provide [block declarations](https://sicstus.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.12.11/html/sicstus/Block-Declarations.html) to make this more smoothly (SWI has a [coarse emulation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/dialect/sicstus/block.pl) for that).

So it is possible to make this even better, but the question remains whether or not this makes much sense. After all, debugging delayed goals becomes more and more difficult with larger programs.

In many situations it is preferable to prevent this and produce an instantiation error in its stead as [`iwhen/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40449516/772868) does:

```
?- iwhen((ground(A);ground(C)),append(A,B,C)).
   error(instantiation_error,iwhen/2).
```

That error is not the nicest answer possible, but at least it is not incorrect. It says: You need to provide more instantiations.

If you **really** want to solve this problem for the general case you have to delve into [E-unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)#E-unification). That is an area with most trivial problem statements and extremely evolved answers. Often, just decidability is non-trivial let alone an effective algorithm. For your particular question, either ACI (for sets) or AN<sub>lr</sub> (for concatenation) are of interest. Where ACI requires solving [Diophantine Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) and associative unification alone is even more complex than that. I am unaware of any such implementation for a Prolog system that solves the general problem.

Prolog IV offered an associative infix operator for concatenation but simply delayed more complex cases. So debugging these remains non-trivial.

Comment: I don't recall noticing SWI-Prolog course emulation before. Will have to remember that. :-)

Comment: *The implementation is realised by creating a wrapper that checks the block conditions..* whereas in SICStus it is much interlaced with indexing.